# How to kill AMCMenu process which uses my whole ram for mac os 10.8.5 macbook pro?

Tags: macos, mac, memory, process

whenever i kill AMCMenu through activity monitor it starts again and uses my ram.
i have restarted my computer many times .please help .

here the link to AMCMenu process sample :
http://forums.macrumors.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=438583&d=1380955778